# Javascript running in a weird way

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

Sorry for the crappy title but I didn't know in which way to put it since I don't really know what's going on at all.

So I have a script that is supposed to every X seconds clear all markers from the google maps Map, then fetch all addresses from from the database with a Ajax call to a PHP script, after this use google's geocoder to get the latitude and longitude of these addresses and push them to a array of markers and finally set the markers on the map. The problem here is that it is only loading one of the markers.

javascript:

```
var lisbon = {lat: 38.736946, lng: -9.142685};
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var markers = [];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: lisbon
});


window.setInterval(function name() {

$.ajax({
    url: "/resources/scripts/php/conn/ajax/getEmployeeMap.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.info("===Restarting markers array===");
        markers = [];
        console.info("===Setting markers array===");
        var data = response;
        var i = 1;
        while (i <= Object.keys(data).length) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': data[i]}, function (results, status) {
                if (status == 'OK') {
                    var geomarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: geomarker
                    });
                    markers.push(marker);
                }
            });
            i++;
        }
        window.setInterval(function () {
            console.info("===Deleting markers from the Map===")
            clearMarkers();
            setMapOnAll(map);
        }, 10000)
    }
});
}, 10000);

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    console.info("===Setting markers on the map===");
    for (var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
}
```

Out put on the console:

> ===Restarting markers array===
>
> ===Setting markers array===
>
> ===Restarting markers array===
>
> ===Setting markers array===
>
> ===Deleting markers from the Map===
>
> ===Setting markers on the map===
>
> ===Setting markers on the map===

JSON coming from PHP:

```
{"1":"Lisboa, Sintra, Rua Professor Rui Luis Gomes 19, 2725-555","2":"Lisboa, Sintra, Rua Professor Rui Luis Gomes 21, 2725-555"}
```

Other weird thing is if I call "setMapOnAll()" without the interval it runs before ajax is done running and setting the array.

When I run the script with only the marker setter it does place the 2 markers so I know it is working.

==UPDATE==

New code, now working, for future reference(my own and other people that might need this):

```
var lisbon = {lat: 38.736946, lng: -9.142685};
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var markers = [];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: lisbon
});

function doMarkers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/resources/scripts/php/conn/ajax/getEmployeeMap.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            clearMarkers();
            var data = response;
            var i = 1;
            while (i <= Object.keys(data).length) {
                geocoder.geocode({'address': data[i]}, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == 'OK') {
                        var geomarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: geomarker
                        });
                        marker.setMap(map);
                        markers.push(marker);
                    }
                });
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
}

// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
    markers.length = 0; //Deletes content from array.
    //This line deleted the array even when setting the markers...
}

doMarkers();
setInterval(doMarkers, 10000);
```

This was remade with both the help of @TonySamperi and @James

Comment: Why not call setMap for each marker from the geocode success callback.

Comment: that really is a really wierd hacky workaround, I'll try the success callback, but how do I call a success callback there? Sorry I'm way too new to javascript, hence I tried to avoid it the max I could in this project but as soon as I reached this part of the project there were too many things to do with JS and now I need to learn it all at the same time xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that this function is asyncronous!

```
 geocoder.geocode({'address': data[i]}, function (results, status) {
```

You can pass a variable to understand when it's the last iteration and then initialize markers on the map

```
var doGeocode = function(address, last){

    geocoder.geocode({'address': data[i]}, function (results, status) {
         if (status == 'OK') {
                var geomarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: geomarker
                });
                markers.push(marker);
          }
         if(last){
            setMapOnAll(map);
         }
     });

}

var getAddresses = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/resources/scripts/php/conn/ajax/getEmployeeMap.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.info("===Restarting markers array===");
            markers = [];
            console.info("===Setting markers array===");
            var data = response;
            var i = 1;
            var count = Object.keys(data).length;
            while (i <= count) {
                doGeoCode(data[i], i == count)
                i++;
           }
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.info("===Deleting markers from the Map===")
                clearMarkers();
                getAddresses(); //auto-call
            }, 5000)
    }
});

getAddresses(); //call manually the first time
```

For anyone who may read this in the future, the setInterval was not the point.

Comment: After changing it to your method the function doesn't run at all :/

Comment: Any errors in console? I made a change..take a look

Comment: no errors, just doesn't run it, testing the new method now.

Comment: samething. The only output in the console is the following:
===Restarting markers array===
===Setting markers array===

Comment: Actually, after running for sometime it set 1 marker.

Comment: Look at the network panel of the console. You should see one call every 10 seconds. Do you have teamviewer?

Comment: yeah I got teamviewer, Ill send you the info in chat.

Comment: Yeah I think so too, my javascript code is awfull in my honest opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148060/discussion-between-mrsanchez-and-tony-samperi).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments if you just set each marker on the map as you receive it, you eliminate one of the setInterval calls.  You do need to change where you delete the map markers so I've put that at the beginning of the AJAX success function.

```
var lisbon = {lat: 38.736946, lng: -9.142685};
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var markers = [];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: lisbon
});


window.setInterval(function name() {

$.ajax({
    url: "/resources/scripts/php/conn/ajax/getEmployeeMap.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.info("===Deleting markers from the Map===")
        clearMarkers();
        console.info("===Restarting markers array===");
        markers = [];
        console.info("===Setting markers array===");
        var data = response;
        var i = 1;
        while (i <= Object.keys(data).length) {
            geocoder.geocode({'address': data[i]}, function (results, status) {
                if (status == 'OK') {
                    var geomarker = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: geomarker
                    });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    markers.push(marker);
                }
            });
            i++;
        }
    }
});
}, 10000);

function clearMarkers() {
    for (var i = 1; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I just tested it and it also works, thanks for the help ;)